# Webscraping 'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found' error

Tags: python, pandas, http-error

I was following a tutorial to webscrape data from yahoo finance, but my code gets this error:

'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found' error.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

amd_profile = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/profile?p=AMD")

print(amd_profile)
```

The errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\x\Desktop\My Python Sandbox Projects\vscode folder 1\code_sandbox.py", line 3, in <module>
    profile = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/profile?p=AMD")
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1085, in read_html      
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables    
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 732, in _build_doc      
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 713, in _build_doc      
    with urlopen(self.io) as f:
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 195, in urlopen       
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick read in the Pandas Documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html?highlight=read_html#pandas.read_html

"A URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML. Note that lxml only accepts the http, ftp and file url protocols. If you have a URL that starts with 'https' you might try removing the 's'."

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I noticed that pandas works with the main yahoo finance summary page but I can't access financials, profiles, etc.

So in your case you can probably read in the main page

this works: amd = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD?p=AMD")

but this doesn't work: amd = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/profile?p=AMD")

Even though both url's exist. I know that doesn't answer the question but at least it narrows down the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33083755)